# Algorithm-generating algorithm

Tags: calculus, functions, algorithms, approximation

Is there an algorithm that can create other algorithms based on any number of arguments? For example, a way to determine a function $ f (x) $ from a given input and a given output? I.e. if $ f (2)=4 $ and $ f (3)= 9$ then a good function that could aproximate these results would be $ f (x)=x^2$. However, is there a method or algorithm to do this? Even if there is an infinite amount of functions that could yield these outputs? Any approximation is good enough if it gives the same answers to the same questions.

Comment: Does the algorithm generate itself?

Comment: There's polynomial interpolation, which fits a polynomial of degree at most n-1 from n inputs

Comment: You should better define the scope of your question.

Comment: It doesn't generate itself, but it could be able to generate something equally complex.

Comment: A function that generates another function is called a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).